# Crystal Report Chart Option in C#

Tags: c#, charts, crystal-reports

I am working in c# windows application.I want to create crystal reports which need a pie chart to show on that report. So just tell me that how can i insert a graph to a crystal report.

I know that clicking on crystal report in the menu bar and then Insert -> Chart.

But here my problem is that the chart button is enable in my form.

[image]

This link helps me to guide in c# crystal report chart.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/crystal-report-showing-graphical-representation-of-data/

How to make the chart button as active. help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first create a report with connection to data store and data field configuration